# n th day from date month

Tags: c#, linq

I am using this to get first business day of month. But how do I use a date range to get first business day of each month for say 2014 to 2030.

```
public static DateTime GetFirstBussinessDayCurrentMonth(DateTime[] holidays)
   {
        return
            Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month))
                .Select(day => new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, day))
                .Where(
                    dt =>
                    dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                    && (holidays == null || !holidays.Any(h => h.Equals(dt))))
                .Min(d => d.Date);
   }
```

Comment: How is `holidays` array populated?

Comment: Instead of `Min` why not use `First` since the dates will be in order.  That way you won't have to create all the dates just to fine the earliest one.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify your method to work with any year and month you throw at it, not just the current date: *(accept a year and month, and use those instead of DateTime.Today)*

```
public static DateTime GetFirstBussinessDayInMonth(int month, int year, DateTime[] holidays)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
                     .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
                     .Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday
                                  && dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday
                                  && (holidays == null || !holidays.Any(h => h.Equals(dt))))
                     .Min(d => d.Date);
}
```

Then call it once for each month of each year you're interested in. Here we're calculating the first business day for each month from 2014 to 2030 and adding them all to a list of DateTimes.

```
var startYear = 2014;
var endYear = 2030;

var businessDays = new List<DateTime>();

for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++)
{
    businessDays.AddRange(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
                  .Select(month => GetFirstBussinessDayInMonth(month, year, holidays)));
                  // not sure where 'holidays' comes from.. I'll assume it's defined
}
```